Can disconnected RDP sessions accumulate and prevent further connections?
I am RDP'ing from one Windows 10 machine to another on the same Ethernet network.  Sometimes the RDP connection is lost, either by me deliberately closing the RDP client app or from being inactive for too long.  When I rerun RDP, I connect to the same computer and all my apps are still present and running.
Sometimes, I get the message that the hostname that I'm trying to reach is not recognized as being a device on the network.  I can physically go to the remote machine, log in, and all the apps are still running, and I can access the internet.  Rebooting the machine allows RDP connections to be made again.
I was told that I have to log out of the remote machine because if the RDP session remains active, they accumulate. At some point I reach my quota.
Is this a plausible explanation?  I am always RDPing to the same machine and from the same machine.

RDP session limits will never result in a network level error like computer not found. your issue is with network stability. all you are doing is reconnecting to a running session. if you do have an issue with session limits, you will get a message to that effect via RDP, not a lower level error. I think you are chasing a wild goose with this hypothesis.

@John: When you say closed normally and properly, I presume that this means pressing the X on the ribbon at the top, or do you mean closing all apps and logging out of the remote Windows account session?

@Frank Thomas: I thought that RDP session limits wouldn't generate such an error.  However, I know that the network is rock stable.  With that in mind, I'm now beginning to wonder whether something running on the remote computer might interfere with its ability to respond to local Ethernet signals.  It doesn't run anything exotic.

The apps running on the remote machine are an Anaconda environment for Python 3.9 to do local data analysis in Spyder; Chrome connecting to Office 365 for email, calendar, Teams web app, and OneDrive; Cygwin running local X-windows, Xterm, and Gvim -- operating almost exclusively on local files; Outlook desktop app (mainly for its Journal function rather than email).  None of these have ever been a problem in the past and a non-RDP context.

Or maybe RDP is malfunctioning or conflicting with something else to interfere with the machine's Ethernet operation, even though there is no rejection at the level of the RDP protocol. It's hard for me to see this as a problem with multiple simultaneous sessions when I'm always running the RDP client on the same computer and connecting to the same remote computer.  Though I have to admit to being very new to RDP

how do you handle machine name resolution? do you have a DNS server, or are you doing hostname lookups using mDNS or somthing else?

@Frank Thomas: I'm not an IT person but ipconfig /all shows a handful of IPv4 addresses for DNS Servers (under Ethernet adapter Ethernet). P.S. I updated my last comment to emphasize why it's hard to see this as a problem with multiple simultaneous sessions.
